# How to fast surround variables or expression (repeating edit) with function in PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, refactoring, pydev

I am using PyDev but I do not know how to fast surround some variable or expressions. Let me explain - I have such code (about 200 similar lines).

```
a = some_func(b)
```

I want to surround `b` with function some transformation and **repeat it 200 in other lines** - so first want mark selection than apply surround - can do it in PyDev with one click/key (or faster than copy begin that copy end).

```
a = some_func(some_surrounding_func(b))
```

or little more complex:

```
a = some_func(some_surrounding_func(b, 1))
```

Normally I am coping `some_surrounding_func(` before `b` than `, 1)` after - it is very unproductive and slow - can I do it faster and skip this unproductive task in Eclipse PyDev?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some alternatives here:

One would be creating a custom scripting command... Although it needs some prep work (to create the command), this should be actually pretty straightforward (and it's definitely useful to know if you have something you'll repeat a lot).

I created an example for you at:

https://gist.github.com/fabioz/d398cfa30960285c869c

-- just download that file with a name pyedit_xxx.py and put it one of the tracked dirs for scripting set in Preferences > Pydev > Scripting PyDev). You probably want to configure the ACTIVATION_STRING (it's bound to 'x' in that example, which means it's activated with Ctrl+2, x) -- you can edit it to change the function for the surround (and anything else you want as a result really) -- note that you have to restart the current PyDev editor to use the script... more details at: http://pydev.org/manual_articles_scripting.html

Another option (if you're using PyDev with LiClipse -- http://www.liclipse.com/) could be using the multiple cursors feature, which can be very handy at this case: http://www.liclipse.com/multi_edition_video.html (i.e.: select all you need and then write the part which comes before and then after once and have it applied to all the selected places at once -- although this would only work if all the occurrences are in the same file).

And yet another option could be using the Practically Macro plugin (https://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/), where you could record a macro and play it back afterwards.

Another option (if you're replacing something you can search with a single regexp) would be making a file search (Ctrl+H) in a regexp mode and then do a replace all which would use the groups of the previously found expression (if you do a regexp replace -- note it'll only be activated if you did a regexp search).

I.e.:

Say you want to search for all names matching 'x', you'd search for a regexp \bx\b then later on you could do a replace for something as my_func($0) -- note that the $0, $1, etc. means the part of the regexp previously matched (so, you can even do things such as invert the order of things there).

Comment: I will test your solutions. I think that is crucial functions.

Comment: Note: I added one more option there (regarding the regexp search/replace with Ctrl+H).

Comment: Regex is nice thing but sometimes better is use surround templates than regex because is too many matches to skip. Surrounding is built in in eclipse I think but is not used in PyDev or switch off.